Software vendor has asked me to give user read write permissions to c:\windows\system folder
In response to a user query a software vendor has suggested that the user have full read/write access to c:\windows\system. I have declined this as no regular user, workgroup or domain user should have access to this folder other than the standard read & execute, list folder contents and read, certainly not write access.
Has anyone else been asked to open the permissions on this folder. Why would the vendor be writing to this folder in the first place.

“Why would the vendor be writing to this folder in the first place.” - A legitimate software developer would never write software that would require access to this particular folder. The only logical conclusion is that the software is malicious

No its not malicious, its a well established software that has been around for years. The client has been using it for 10 years at least and this is the first time I've heard this. The Helpdesk response is BS as far as I'm concerned and clearly has no idea what they are talking about when requesting such a change. It was one of those "I doubt myself moments" hence my post.

I respectfully disagree that legitimate software would ever need elevated permissions to system folders. I have been a Windows developer for almost 3 decades. I have never written software that requires it.

If the software is particularly ancient and badly written then it might need to write to those folders, but on modern systems that should be caught and sent to a virtual folder in the users profile. No well written modern software should require access to those folders unless they are intended to always be run as an administrator and to be constantly editing files in there, for example some software may be rewriting the hosts file to block sites. For normal users allowing the level of access they are suggesting is a massive security risk and no real IT person would or should allow it.

I have not changed the permissions and never will. As I mentioned the software vendor helpdesk have suggested this and I have said no way. I also develop desktop apps and have never has reason to write to this or any other windows folder. The software in question is legitmate palletising software but old I mean very old written back in 2003, yet never has it required access to this folder until apparently now. We have been pursuing the vendor for an upgrade to the system but they seem reluctant because the original was customised for this client.

Meant to add as well that the software has not been upgraded recently either so there is no way there is any need for these changes.

@Mokubai, the hosts files resides under the system32 folder, I'm  referring to the systems folder (c:\windows\system) folder.

If you must run this faulty software, then run it in a self-contained environment. There, you can grant all access they request, with much less fear it could harm the system.

Easiest is to run it in a sandbox environment, such as free Sandboxie or an alternative. A sandbox basically makes a copy of the existing OS to run software safely.
Only slightly more involved is creating a virtual machine (VM), such as Oracle's free VirtualBox or an alternative and running the software in that environment. An advantage of a VM is that it can have a different OS from that on the PC. For example, if that two-decades-old palletising software won't run on Windows 11, but works on Windows NT 4.2 or XP, then set up a VM on a Windows 11 PC with NT or XP. One can even run 32-bit software on 64-bit hardware using a VM.

There are "gotchas". Communications from within the sandbox or VM to the outside environment needs to be enabled to share a printer or network drive, for example. However, once done, that VM can be copied to other machines when upgrading hardware, and it would provide continuous service with low maintenance.

The client has been using this software for around 15 years without an issue then suddenly they are having some issues that have never surfaced before and the support response is to open the permissions on a Windows folder, something that I have not had to do on new installations of the same software across 3 new PC's in recent weeks, all running Windows 11. I will not be going to the trouble of sandboxing anything for the client for an issue that hasn't been an issue for 15 years and no other user on the network using the same software has experienced the same issue.
